# I had some questions on db_redir_temp

Tags: nutch, nutch2

I had injected some urls to crawl that is one round and I found some urls as db_redir_temp.
{"url":"http://www.universityhealth.org","pst":"temp_moved(13), lastModified=0: [https://www.universityhealth.org/"}](https://www.universityhealth.org/%22%7D)
{"url":"http://silvercappartners.com","pst":"temp_moved(13), lastModified=0: [http://silvercappartners.com/index.html"}](http://silvercappartners.com/index.html%22%7D)

may i know that the http://www.universityhealth.org is pointing to same url why it is showed db_redir_temp.
This url is pointing to  http://silvercappartners.com to this url http://silvercappartners.com/index.html
should I consider the pst column will give the redirected url page.

Answer (score 1):

The two URLs

```
http://www.universityhealth.org
https://www.universityhealth.org/
```

differ in one important point, the protocol (or scheme) - `http` vs. `https`. These are not always equivalent, eg. a web server may not support `https`. The other point (the trailing `/`) is irrelevant, the HTTP request for both the empty path and the server root path is `GET / HTTP/1.1` (maybe using a different protocol version).

But true reason is simply that the server responded with `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` which is a redirect, see [HTTP 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302).

The "pst" or "protocol status" metadata field may include a message. For redirects it contains the redirect target.